# VAULT - How to unwrap Secret ID with HTTP request

Tags: http, hashicorp-vault

I want to integrate vault with a Java application. I follow this [blog](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/how-and-why-to-use-approle-correctly-in-hashicorp-vault) to do it.

[image]

The question is when I have wrapping token, I want to Unwrap it in step number 9 in the picture above with HTTP request and get the `secret_id`. I see the API document in [here](https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/system/wrapping-unwrap), but it require `X-Vault-Token` which can not store in my JAVA application. Without it the API response `permission denied`.

But when I use vault command: `VAULT_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxxx vault unwrap -field=secret_id`, it response a secret that what I want (I do not login to Vault).

Any have experience about this please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your linked diagram, step 10 (the next step) is literally "Login with Role ID and Secret ID". If you want to wrap a different secret, then you can change the pattern completely, but the blog post you're referencing wants you to use the Secret ID from the wrapped token response to then log into Vault with that role and get your final secrets.

So, take the output of `SECRET_ID=$(VAULT_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxxx vault unwrap -field=secret_id)`, export it, and then run a `resp=$(vault write auth/approle/login role_id="${ROLE_ID}" secret_id="${SECRET_ID}"); VAULT_TOKEN=$(echo "${resp}" | jq -r .auth.client_token)`, export the VAULT_TOKEN, then call Vault to get the secret you really want (`vault kv get secret/path/to/foobar`) and do something with it.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
wrap_token=$(cat ./wrapped_token.txt)
role_id=$(cat ./approle_role_id.txt)

secret_id=$(VAULT_TOKEN="${wrap_token}" vault unwrap -field=secret_id)

resp=$(vault write -format=json auth/approle/login role_id="${role_id}" secret_id="${secret_id}")
VAULT_TOKEN=$(echo "${resp}" | jq -r '.auth.client_token')
export VAULT_TOKEN

# Put a secret in a file
# Best to ensure that the fs permissions are suitably restricted
UMASK=0077 vault kv get -format=json path/to/secret > ./secret_sink.json

# Put a secret in an environment variable
SECRET=$(vault kv get -format=json path/to/secret)
export SECRET
```

In case you want to reduce the security of your pattern, you can read below...

> If you want to avoid logging into Vault and simply give the app a secret, you can avoid many of these steps by having your trusted CI solution request the secret directly, i.e. `vault kv get -wrap_ttl=24h secret/path/to/secret`, and then the unwrapping step you're doing will actually contain a secret you want to use, instead of the intermediary secret that would allow you to log into Vault and establish an application identity. However, this is not recommended as it would make your CI solution want to access more secrets, which is far from least privilege, and it makes it incredibly difficult to audit where the secrets are actually being leveraged from a Vault perspective, which is one of the primary benefits of implementing a central secrets management solution like Vault.